# Ubuntu 20.04 Android USB connectivity problems

Tags: usb, android

I have searched the forums but have found no solution to my problem.  I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with an Android Pixel 6.

The problem is that the phone will only be recognized when plugged into one of my four USB ports. When I try `lsusb` on the USB-C port I see no entry for the phone. On another USB port I see an entry from `lsusb` but the phone mounts then dismounts and this continues in a endless loop. On another port `lsusb` doesn't see the phone at all.  I have tried multiple cables to no avail.  On the USB-C port I get this output from `dmesg`:

```
[ 4480.033608] usb usb1-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 4480.933122] usb usb1-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 4480.933213] usb usb1-port1: attempt power cycle
[ 4482.771712] usb usb1-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 4483.671980] usb usb1-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 4483.672058] usb usb1-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
[ 4487.594018] usb usb1-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 4488.493290] usb usb1-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 4488.493366] usb usb1-port1: attempt power cycle
[ 4491.483826] usb usb1-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 4492.382882] usb usb1-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 4492.382956] usb usb1-port1: attempt power cycle
[ 4495.341354] usb usb1-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 4496.240904] usb usb1-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 4496.240973] usb usb1-port1: attempt power cycle
[ 4499.159455] usb usb1-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 4500.063463] usb usb1-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 4500.063538] usb usb1-port1: attempt power cycle
[ 4501.282393] usb usb1-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 4502.186004] usb usb1-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 4502.186068] usb usb1-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
```

However other USB devices such as Blu-Ray drive or USB storage work just fine.

Here is `lsusb` with nothing plugged in:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 04f3:0903 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 13d3:56dd IMC Networks USB2.0 Hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 13d3:3526 IMC Networks USB2.0-CRW
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Am I experiencing some sort of driver error?  I'm stuck and not sure what to do.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like the phone does not like the USB-C port. Not a Ubuntu problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a bios issue (Lenovo ideapad 330S-14IKB). After updating to latest bios, any Android device worked via usb-c

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1234243)